# custom grid component react, background image

Tags: reactjs, image, background, styling

I have a component in react, a custom grid that I want to use twice in the same page but with different background images, I would like to pass this images with props form the root component, what is the right way to do it?
and it is a good idea to do this at all? 
this code I wrote is working but i'm not sure is the right thing to do

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InnerTextGridCategory from './InnerTextGridCategory';
import InnerTextGridTitle from './InnerTextGridTitle';
import PlayLink from './PlayLink';

class CustomGrid extends Component {

render() {
    const styles = {
        img1: {
            background: `linear-gradient(61deg, #000000 0%, rgba(0, 0, 
            0, 0) 70%),url(${this.props.img1})`,
            backgroundSize: `cover`,
            backgroundPosition: `center`,
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className={`${this.props.gridSize}`}>
            <div className={`${this.props.gridSize} item1`} style= 
{styles.img1}>
                <div className="wrapper-text-grid">`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can't hardcode these image URLs in CSS but you a going to get them from props I don't see a better way to do it.

Here what React docs say:

> Some examples in the documentation use style for convenience, but using the style attribute as the primary means of styling elements is generally not recommended. In most cases, className should be used to reference classes defined in an external CSS stylesheet. **style is most often used in React applications to add dynamically-computed styles at render time**.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-use-inline-styles

BTW, you can set all the static props in CSS and leave just image to inline styles

Comment: finally I added the background images adding clases through props